# Number of $3$-digit numbers after getting rid of permutations

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations of $3$-digit numbers are there from $000-999$, where the ordering of the digits don't matter. In this case, $112$ would be the same as $121$ and $211$ and so the set would contain only one of them.

I think I might have worked it out by partitioning it into $3$ cases:

case 1: all digits are the same $= 10$

case 2: $1$ digit is the same, $2$ digits are different $= 10 \cdot 9 = 90$

case 3: all digits are different $= \binom{10}{3} = 120$

so case 1 + case 2 + case 3 $= 220$

Comment: You should be able to work this out fairly easily using combinatorics

Comment: I think I might have worked it out by partitioning it into 3 cases:                     
 **case 1:** all digits are the same = 10,                                                                              **case 2:** 1 digit is the same, 2 digits are different = 10 * 9 = 90,                                  **case 3:** all digits are different = 10 choose 3 = 120,                                                so case 1 + case 2 + case 3 = 220?

Comment: that seems about right

Comment: Your count is correct.  It would be better to describe case 2 as two distinct digits are used, one of which is used twice and the other of which is used once.